# HTML spinner not spinning in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using icon-font spinner for showing something is processing.
But the spinner is not spinning in firefox
This is my less code

```
.animation (@params) {
    -webkit-animation:@params;
    -o-animation:@params;
    animation:@params;
}

.spin {
    .animation(spin 1500ms infinite linear);
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-o-keyframes spin {
    to { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

This is my html code

```
<div ng-if="showProgressBar" class="spin icon-spinner">
</div>
```

It is working fine in chrome. In firefox I am able to see static icon not spinning icon

Comment: Add `-moz` vendor prefix too to your stylings and check.

Comment: seems you are using Older version Firefox.  use `-moz` prefix.

Comment: I have firefox version 30.
I beleive in this version vendor prefix not needed

Comment: Resolved I have to wrap spinner inside another div